# C - Depth first search in adjacency matrix using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, adjacency-matrix

I have a recursion problem I would like to solve using recursion.

For example, given this adjacency matrix AdjMat:

```
  0 1 2 3 
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0
2 0 1 0 1
3 0 0 1 0
```

Say I would like to look at column 0 and all of its neighbors, and its neighbors' neighbors (distance of 2), and store all of the row indices > 0 into a linked list of ints.

Here is my updated code:

```c
intNode *Neighbors(intNode *head, int colOfInterest, int distance) {
    int x = colOfInterest; 

    if (distance == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
               if (AdjMat[x][j] > 0) { 
                   head = insertInt(head, j);
               }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    intNode *subpath = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
        subpath = Neighbors(head, colOfInterest, distance);
    }
    // Once the final neighbor column has been reached, add elements to the linked list.
    return head;
}
```

It currently does not return the expected output (which is 0, 1, and 2 in the linked list), but I am not sure why. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: The question is impossible to answer in its current form. What are `k`, `h`, `source_ingredient`, `dist` ?

Comment: Sorry for that, please see the updated code.

Comment: Sorry, but it's better to copy/paste your *actual code* as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, than to make random adjustments to the post.

Comment: Hm. When you call `nearestNeighbors` recursively, you'll probably want to save the return value, i.e. the new list head. And you should make up your mind whether you want to use recursion or iteration through loops. Your code seems to be an unholy mixture of both.

Comment: Can you explain in pseudo code what that loop is supposed to do? Currently you visit cells multiple times, I think you need clear rules for stopping the recursion. But I simply do not understand what it should do.

Comment: The recursion is called with the same values as the current incarnation.

Comment: The while loop is supposed to iterate over up to n columns where n is specified by the ```distance``` parameter. The double for loop is supposed to iterate over each row index for the ColOfInterest.

Comment: Reread what you just wrote, @leftail.  You've just described how you think all the iteration involved addresses every aspect of the problem.  So what role does recursion have to play?

Comment: If it is essential to solve the problem using recursion, then I suspect you've approached it backwards.  Instead of devising a recursive formulation of a solution and then implementing it, you appear to have devised a solution and then tried to plug some recursion into it.

Comment: Yes @JohnBollinger, you're correct. I'm not sure how to solve this in recursion and that requirement is essential as you said.

Comment: As I said, before trying to implement it, formulate the problem recursively.  For example, suppose you want to compute the set, *N(d)*, of nodes reachable from the start node via a path of length *d*.  Well we can define this recursively, as all the nodes adjacent to any node in *N(d - 1)*.  If we then let *N(0)* be the set containing (only) the starting node, then we have a complete basis for a solution.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, I think I'm a step closer now. I updated the code above. I'm just not sure how the recursive step should be incorporated. Is a simple call to the function enough?

Comment: You might well need a status to mark which elements have been visited, to prevent the recursion repeating where it's been.

Comment: I think you're tweaking details and ignoring the big picture.  Yours is not an implementation problem (yet), it is a *design* problem.  How is the function *supposed* to work?  How does it define its own results in terms of the results of one or more calls to itself?  That is for you to determine, and you need to determine it before you can implement it.

Comment: My understanding is that the recursive step will fit right before I can start adding the elements to the linked list. This way, I can reach the final neighbor column and then traverse backwards as I add each element. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have two major misconceptions in your code. The first is about recursion and the second is about how an adjacency matrix works.

The recursion basically works like this:

- take a node and a max. distance: `func(node, d)`;
- if the distance is negative, return
- add the node to the list;
- for all adjacent nodes, call the function on that node and with a new, now shorter distance: `func(next, d - dist(node, next)`.

To find all nodes in the vicinity of node #0, you'd start with an empty list and then call `func(0, 2)`, which will lead to the following calls:

```
func(0, 2)                  // list {0}
    func(1, 1)              // list {0, 1}
        func(0, 0)          // list {0, 1, 0}          error, see below
            func(1, -1)     // negative d, do nothing
        func(2, 0)          // list {0, 1, 0, 2}
             func(1, -1)    // negative d, do nothing
             func(3, -1)    // negative d, do nothing

--> recursion depth
```

This recursion will eventually stop, because you diminish the distance in each step. This is important: Every recursion must have a termination condition otherwise it would recurse endlessly. (It is a matter of style whether you test the distance up front or when you recurse. Up font catches invalid input early, but may lead to useless "dead" recursions.)

The recursion as given has a subtle problem: When you call `func(0, 2)` the function will add node #0 twice, because going from node 0 to 1 and then back to 0 yields a distance of 2, which is within reach. There are several ways to solve this. For example you could look whether the given node is already in your list. Or you could flag nodes as visited as you go.

The adjacency matrix determines whether two nodes are connected. Two nodes `a` and `b` are connected if `adj[a][b] != 0`. That means that if you want to find all neighbours `next` of a given node `node`, you should do something like this:

```
for (int next = 0; next < N; next++) {
    if (adj[node][next]) {
        // do something with next
    }
}
```

You don't need two nested loops. The matrix has two dimensions, but the first one is always fixed: it's the source node. (If you look at your code, you'll see that you don't do anything with `i`.)

In your case, the adjacency matrix seems to have values of 0 and 1 only, but it could have other non-zero values to indicate the distances of a weighted graph.